# When traveling from Kosovo to the USA, how many stops in the Schengen zone as a transit are allowed?

Tags: usa, schengen, transit-visas

I'm holding a Kosovar passport and tourist USA visa.

I expect to need to transit in the Schengen Zone, but I do not have much information yet.

Answer (score 2):

- More than one stop would mean that you travel an *internal* flight between the two transfers, so there is no airside transit.
- Generally speaking, Kosovo citizens still require a visa to enter the Schengen area. I believe there are exceptions for Croatia.